# Azure Search SDK Regex?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I see that Azure Search supports Lucene Regex from here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589323.aspx#bkmk_regex but no where does it describe how to do this with the SDK.  Before I abandon all hope, I was wondering if anyone has tried it and succeeded?

My team and I have looked at this for days trying to figure out how the fuzzy search works and to be honest this tool looks very limited compared to others on the market.  Just wanted to see if anyone out there has done this.

API Version: 2015-02-28

Here is what I've found thus far:

@ this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/search/search-query-lucene-examples.md

Example 8 -- Right-click the query. Search for jobs with either the term Senior or Junior.

```
&queryType=full&$select=business_title&search=business_title:/(Sen|Jun)ior/
```

On the Portal.Azure.com (where my search explorer is...) I type the following item in `$select=CaseNumber&search=/508(0|1)/`  where I'm trying to find all case numbers with 508 and ending in either 0 or 1.  Here is my results:

```
/$metadata#docs(CaseNumber)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.13246636,
            "CaseNumber": "16-A-1238"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.025094833,
            "CaseNumber": "SUV2014000179"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if I do this: `$select=CaseNumber&search=/5080(0|1)/`

```
/$metadata#docs(CaseNumber)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.33221063,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP238-5080"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.13288425,
            "CaseNumber": "16-A-1238"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.025173998,
            "CaseNumber": "SUV2014000179"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I finally get a single case with the number I'm attempting to match...  I'm going to say that something in the algorithm isn't working, or isn't working as described.

Now assuming this was REALLY RegEx I should be able to do this /508.+/ and get anything that starts with 508 but since the simple examples don't seem to be bringing back the appropriate results I'm going to go with no.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so we've managed to correct the issue with what we were seeing and in order to do so we had to remove the SDK from our indexer code.  Reference this URL: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/

```
analyzers = new[]{
     new Analyzer(){
         name = "my_default",
         type = "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
         tokenizer = "standard",
         tokenFilters = new List<string>(){
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "phonetic",
                "trim",
                "my_edgeNGram" }
     },
},
tokenFilters = new[]{
     new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(){
          name = "my_edgeNGram",
          type = "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilter",
          minGram = 2,
          maxGram = 50}
     }
```

This now allows for more accurate 'fuzzy' searching without having to use RegEx to get what I want.  See the following:

```
$select=CaseNumber&search=508&searchFields=CaseNumber
```

This returned the following:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "{MyURL}",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 5.188466,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP238-5080"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.6886727,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:501-6432"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.6886727,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:505-532"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.6886727,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:509-1851"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.6886727,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:784-5069"
        }
    ]
}
```

So for those of you looking at how to do some of the things using the SDK, unfortunately I couldn't figure out the index part using it.  We still use the SDK to query the data without issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, another thing I've been able to find is that partial search inside a string phrase is not found.  For example, this was my original search query string:

```
$select=CaseNumber&search=5080&searchFields=CaseNumber
```

Results:

```
/$metadata#docs(CaseNumber)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 6.5489187,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP238-5080"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.8920381,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:501-6432"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.8920381,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:505-532"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.8920381,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:509-1851"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.337873,
            "CaseNumber": "SUP:784-5069"
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I attempt to search for 080 in any capacity (using *, ~, or any RegEx) as shown below:

```
1. $select=CaseNumber&search=080&searchFields=CaseNumber
2. $select=CaseNumber&search=*080&searchFields=CaseNumber

/$metadata#docs(CaseNumber)",
    "value": []
}
```

What we ended up having to do is create a list of strings that contained permutations for each CaseNumber field stripping off the first character.  For example:

```
SUP2385080
UP2385080
P2385080
2385080
385080
85080
5080
080
```

This now allows us to search a 'CaseNumbers' list of strings for any partial string matching and seems to return back the closest match thus far.